# Firebase 3 - update data by pressing like/unlike

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have made app that saves and receive data (database) from Firebase.
For posting data in app, you do not need to be logged in, even registrated.

It is simple app made for having fun, so everyone can post and like others post.

Everything is fine with writing data to Firebase and retrieving data prom it, but I have problem with likes.

I have tried several code, but I don't know if I am messing up with second child, or even code is not good enough.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likeLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var bckgView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var unlikeButton: UIButton!

var postID: String!

@IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.likeButton.isEnabled = false
    /*let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key*/

    ref.child("Frusters").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

         if let likes = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

                        let count = likes.count
                        self.likeLabel.text = "\(count) Likes"

                        let update = ["likes" : count]
                        ref.child("Frusters").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(update)

                        self.likeButton.isHidden = true
                        self.unlikeButton.isHidden = false
                        self.likeButton.isEnabled = true
                        }

    })

    ref.removeAllObservers()
    }


@IBAction func unlikePressed(_ sender: Any) {

  }
 }
```

When I run this code, everything is OK, until I press Like, then I got this error:

[image]

I have tried several other .child ways instead "postID", nothing works. Watching this code all day and change it a lot, but no results.

Can you please help? What am I doing wrong?

This is my Firebase nod:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The error indicates you're unwrapping a nil value. From the look of your code, you may not have assigned a value to `postID` before unwrapping it. Try a print statement before calling `observe` to see if `postID` = `nil`

Comment: I have separate file: "class Post: NSObject" where I have added var 'postID: String!' if is what you meant?

Comment: in `PostTableViewCell`, you have `var postID: String!`. If you try to use `postID` before you've assigned it a value, you will get an error because you're trying to access something that doesn't yet exist. So where are you assigning a value to `postID`? What happened when you added the `print` statement?

Comment: Yep @Jen, you are right. I needed to assign postID to TableView and save it with post, also load it with post to my feed. Then worked, but still something is wrong. I must correct my code somewhere, because it count one and same likes to all post... Need to sit a little more in front of this code :D Thanks